# Problem 6 chapter 9 PMA Rudin existence

Tags: real-analysis, linear-transformations

My question is in regards to "exist at every point".

I am trying to show if $f(0,0)=0$ and f(x,y)= $\frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ if (x,y)$\neq(0,0)$.
Prove  $D_1f(x,y) and D_2f(x,y)$ exist at every point of $R^2$.

I could show that $D_1f(x,0) =D_2f(0,y)=0$ And then the partial derivatives exist at (0,0) and thus exist for every point.

But I need to show it using the definition of partial derivative

$$\lim_{h\to 0 }{ \frac{||f(x+he_j)-f(x)-(Ahe_j)||}{||h||}=0}$$

If $f : R^n → R^m $ is differentiable at a point $ a ∈ R^n$
if there exists a linear transformation $ A : R^n → R^m$

I am uncertain as to how to show existence given linear transformation definition given for partial derivative in chpt9.

What is throwing me is if I am defining my $ f $ as a linear transformation in the form similar to:

[partial derivative as Linear Transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPDWN.jpg)

Problem 6's function refers to the partial derivatives $D_1f(x,y),D_2f(x,y)$ does that mean by the definition of partials, as given in Defn 9.16 and thrm 9.17?

Given the comments, I'm adding this attempt. Am I on the right track?
$$\lim_{h\to 0 }{ \frac{||\frac{(x+h)*y}{(x+h)^2+y^2}-\frac{x*y}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{y*(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}*h||}{||h||}=0}$$

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $f:\Bbb{R}^2\to\Bbb{R}^1$, so that the norm in the numerator is in fact nothing but absolute value. Furthermore since you are computing the partial derivatives you can instead use $(h,0)$ in the denominator, so that $\Vert(h,0)\Vert=\sqrt{h^2}=\vert h\vert$ as well, and the whole expression reduces to computing

$$\lim_{h\in\Bbb{R}\\h\to0}\dfrac{f(x+h,y)-f(x,y)}{h}.$$

The reason why you need to use a quotient of norms in the general case is that otherwise division (rate of change) does not make sense in general (the numerator is in the target space and the denominator is in the domain).

Comment: Thank you for the comments (about formatting too). What I would like to clearly understand is the show it exists. If I show the partial with respect to variable 1 or variable 2 has a limit, have I proven existence? In Rudin's book the Ah which is actually f'h is critical to the definition of differentiability as is the partial defined as $\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{f_i(x+te_j)-f_i(x)}{t}$. When it comes to partial derivative, I cannot clearly see what is needed to prove existence.

Comment: You can just compute using the expression I provided. In this case you can actually divide $Ah$ by $h$ and send it to the other side as it's a constant in $h$. Thus the limit will be $A$ itself.