# Differentiability at undefined point.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Given $f  : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, the derivative $f'(x)$ is the linear operator such that  $$\frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-f'(x)h|}{|h|} $$ is smaller than $\varepsilon$ if $|h|$ is smaller than $\delta$. The partial derivative $D_if$  is just that $$\frac{|f(x+te_i)-f(x)-D_ift|}{|t|}$$ is arbitrarily small as $t$ gets small enough.

The function $$f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$$ is undefined at $(0,0)$. Rudin says that its partial derivative exits everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  However, if we plug this into the partial derivative definition and evaluate at $(0,0)$, we clearly have $f(0,0)$ undefined in the expression.  But I know $f(x,0)=0$ for all $x$. I can kinda say $f'(0,0) = 0$. But if we stick with the limit definition, since the limit definition require the expression $f(0,0)$, it shouldn't be defined right?

Furthermore, if the partial derivative $D_if'(x,y)$ does exist everywhere, and is continuous, this would mean the existence of the linear operator $f'(x,y)$ satisfying the derivative definition.  This again comeback to the definition of the linear operator which require evaluation of $f(0,0)$.

I wonder if there is a well defined notion of differentiability at point where the function is not even defined? I tried to come up with one, and the following is my attempt:

$f'(a)$ exits if the closure of the graph $(x,f'(x))$ is continuous at $x=a$? The closure is taken with respect to the product topology of two metric spaces $X$ and $Y$. $f: X \to Y$, of course.

Comment: You should check to text to ensure that the function really isn't defined at the origin.  My recollection is that Rudin defines the function to be zero there.

Comment: Indeed, this appears to be Exercise 6 on page 239 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.  The goal of this exercise is to look at a function which has partial derivatives everywhere, yet is nevertheless not continuous everywhere.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Oh, Thank you so much, I over looked f(0,0)=0 at the beginning.  So basically, if a function is not defined at a point, then it can't be differentiable at that point right? I can't se where $D_if$ is not continuous.

Comment: I'm honestly a little surprised that this has not been asked here before, but I can't find a good duplicate question.  The nearest thing I can find is [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258248/problem-6-chapter-9-pma-rudin-existence), but the confusion seems to be different, and the answer there is unsatisfactory for the question being asked here.

Comment: Derivatives and partial derivatives are defined on some subset of the interior of the domain of the function.  If a function is not defined at a point, then it cannot have a (partial) derivative at that point.  The goal of this exercise is to show that existence of partial derivatives is not sufficient to show existence of the derivative, and that a function can have partial derivatives *and* fail to be continuous.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thank you so much. I see it is not continuous at 0 since at 0, the partial derivative is 0 whereas at points closed to 0, but not on the two axis, they blow up.

Comment: Besides what @XanderHenderson wrote, you wrote "I know $f(x,0)=0$ for all $x$.", which is (given your 'definition' of $f$) of course false. Your mistake is in assuming $0/x = 0$ for all real $x$. More seriously, you should not even write any expression that is ill-defined; you can only write "$x/y$" in a context where the "$/$" operation is well-defined on the inputs $x,y$. If you always be careful this way, you would have caught the error right at the 'definition' of $f$.